# Enterprise Linux: /scratch is mounted on a LV but the LV doesn't shown when running lvs

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-volume, oracle-linux

Took over a few Oracle Linux VMs from another team and found this weird situation. The /scratch is mounted on a logical volume according to them, but seems that the system is having some error and the corresponding LV is actually missing.

```
# df -h | grep scratch
/dev/mapper/vg01-lv_scratch
                       98G  696M   92G   1% /scratch
```

But `lvs` doesn't show this `vg01-lv_scratch` while it's supposed to, compared to some normal status hosts.

```
lvs
  LV      VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root vg00 -wi-ao---- 51.00g
  lv_swap vg00 -wi-ao----  8.00g
```

The folder itself works fine right now, but when we tried to reboot one of the VM, and it'll fail to find `/dev/mapper/vg01-lv_scratch` to mount.

I'm curious how it can end up like this? If the LV is missing, shouldn't the mounted file-system stop working as well? If it's still working fine, where exactly it is mounted at and where can we find the data? Or fix this situation?

Comment: Have you tried: lvs vg01?  It may be the vg00 is the default for the command.

Comment: No luck. Looks like vg01 is really not there, as a reboot will fail when the system will try to mount back vg01-lv_scratch. But if we leave the VM there for now it'll work, kinda like in a limbo state.